# Cloning objects in Scheme

Tags: object, racket, cloning

I was trying to clone an object in Scheme, something like

```
(define o1
    (new cl%
        [a 1] [b 2]))
```

and then

```
(define o2 o1)
```

When I used set! on o1, it changed o2 along with o1. But I want independent cloning with same attributes. What should I do?

Comment: "When I used set! on o1, it changed o2 along with o1." That is not possible. Show your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a copy method.  Then:

```
(define o2 (copy-cl%-thingy o1))
```

Like this:

```
(define (new aval bval)
  `(cl% [a ,aval] [b ,bval]))
(define cl%-aval caddr)
(define cl%-bval cadddr)

(define (copy-cl%-thingy o)
  (new (cl%-aval o) (cl%-bval o)))
```